# 128-bit arithmetic on x64 in C

Tags: c, integer, x86-64, biginteger, 128-bit

When implementing bignums on x86, obviously the most efficient choice for digit size is 32 bits. However, you need arithmetic up to twice the digit size (i.e. 32+32=33, 32*32=64, 64/32=32). Fortunately, not only does x86 provide this, but it's also accessible from portable C (`uint64_t`).

Similarly, on x64 it would be desirable to use 64-bit digits. This would require 128 bit arithmetic (i.e. 64+64=65, 64*64=128, 128/64=64). Fortunately, x64 provides this. Unfortunately, it's not accessible from portable C, though obviously one could dip into assembly.

So my question is whether it's accessible from non-portable C. Do any C compilers on x64 provide access to this, and if so, what's the syntax?

(Note that I'm not talking about 128-bit vectors that are strictly treated as collections of 32 or 64-bit words with no carry propagation between them, but about actual 128-bit integer operations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC 4.1 introduced initial 128-bit integer support with the `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t` built-in types but 128-bit type was officially released since [GCC 4.6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html) as [`__int128` / `unsigned __int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html)

Clang also supports those types although I don't know since when. The first version on [Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) (3.0.0) does support `__int128_t` though

ICC gained the same support since version 13.0.0: [128-bit integers supporting +, -, *, /, and % in the Intel C Compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16365840/995714)

See also

- [Is there a 128 bit integer in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16088282/995714)
- [What gcc versions support the __int128 intrinsic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21886985/995714)

---

If you're on MSVC then there's no direct support for a 128-bit type but there are many intrinsics helping you do 128-bit operations:

- 64*64→128: [`_mul128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/mul128?view=vs-2019), [`_umul128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/umul128?view=vs-2019), [`__mulh()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/mulh?view=vs-2019), [`__umulh()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/umulh?view=vs-2019)
- 128/64→64: [`_div128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/div128?view=vs-2019), [`_udiv128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/udiv128?view=vs-2019)
- 64+64→65: The carry in an addition can be easily obtained by comparing the low part of the sum with any of the operands:

  ```
  struct uint128 {
      uint64_t H, L;
  };

  inline uint128 add(uint128 a, uint128 b)
  {
      uint128 c;
      c.L = a.L + b.L;                // add low parts
      c.H = a.H + b.H + (c.L < a.L);  // add high parts and carry
      return c;
  }
  ```
- 64-64→65: We can use the same method for subtraction as in addition

  ```
  inline uint128 sub(uint128 a, uint128 b)
  {
      uint128 c;
      c.L = a.L - b.L;
      c.H = a.H - b.H - (c.L > a.L);
      return c;
  }
  ```

There are also intrinsics for shifting although implementing these is trivial: [`__shiftleft128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/shiftleft128?view=vs-2019), [`__shiftright128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/shiftright128?view=vs-2019)

---

If you're on an unsupported compiler then just use some fixed-width types from many available libraries, that would be much faster. For example [`ttmath:UInt<4>`](https://www.ttmath.org/) (a 128-bit int type with four 32-bit limbs), or `(u)int128_t` in [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut.html) and [calccrypto/uint128_t](https://github.com/calccrypto/uint128_t). An arbitrary-precision arithmetic library like GMP is just too costly for this. One example: [Optimization story: Switching from GMP to gcc's `__int128` reduced run time by 95%](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10909909)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library:

http://gmplib.org/