# GCC alternative for Linux supporting OpenMP and 128-bit integers with +, -, *, /, and %

Tags: c, linux, integer, int128

I have a C code that uses OpenMP and 128-bit integers. For the 128-bit integers, I'm using the __int128_t and __uint128_t extensions provided by GCC. I'm looking for *any* other compiler that can also compile this kind of code.

Clang supports __uint128_t, but not OpenMP. ICC supports OpenMP, but not 128-bit integers [(at least not ones that you can use built-in operators like +, -, *, /, and % with)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365840/128-bit-integers-supporting-and-in-the-intel-c-compiler). The [Portland Group C Compiler](http://www.pgroup.com/) doesn't natively support 128-bit arithmetic.

Just to be clear, I'm looking for 128-bit integers analogous to __int128_t that work as drop-in replacements for "normal" integers. Is there any compiler for Linux besides GCC that supports OpenMP and 128-bit integers, with the built-in operators +, -, *, /, and %?

Comment: Why would you like to change compilers?

Comment: @Jens In order to double-check my calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICC didn't support __int128_t with version 12 (when this question was posted), but supported was added with versions 13 onwards, see: [128-bit integers supporting +, -, *, /, and % in the Intel C Compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365840/128-bit-integers-supporting-and-in-the-intel-c-compiler)