# What gcc versions support the __int128 intrinsic type?

Tags: gcc, 128-bit, extended-precision

Under the [gcc docs 128-bit](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) integers is:

> As an extension the integer scalar type `__int128` is supported for targets which have an integer mode wide enough to hold 128 bits.
>   Simply write `__int128` for a signed 128-bit integer, or `unsigned __int128` for an unsigned 128-bit integer.
>
> There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer constant of type `__int128` for targets with
>   long long integer less than 128 bits wide.

I was wondering what gcc version added support for this type, or if there's a macro that can be used directly to test for its existence.

Comment: For AMD64: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329541/does-gcc-support-128-bit-int-on-amd64

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure about the first version, but you can test for the `__SIZEOF_INT128__` macro - which is (typically) `16` if defined.

Answer (score 9):

Get the source and:

```
git log --reverse --grep='__int128'
```

to see the first occurrence of the word on a commit message.

This leads us to: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/6388cfe24f7ecbdc2ba2d4c80638ea6c95ba07c2 which says:

```
Add __int128 keyword.
```

Then list all tags that contain that commit with:

```
git tag --contains 6388cfe24f7ecbdc2ba2d4c80638ea6c95ba07c2
```

and the earliest one is:

```
gcc-4_6_0-release
```

TODO: there is also an earlier reference to `__int128_t` which I did not understand. What is the difference between `__int128` and `_int128_t`?

Comment: Normally, _t suffix means a typedef, __ prefix means reserved for compiler and _ prefix means reserved for standard library; I would guess that __int128 is the final native type supported by the compiler, while _int128_t was a temporary hack that they moved away from.

Comment: searching for `__int128` doesn't work, because it was `__int128_t` on older gcc versions. 128-bit int has been supported since [at least gcc 4.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5576526/995714)