# How to get single-operand imul from C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86

What do I have to write in C to get the assembler to show the `imul` with one operand? For example:

```
imul  %ebp
```

Comment: There's no rule that requires a compiler-writer to use a particular instruction. So there's no answer to your question beyond what might  happen to work with a particular compiler at a particular version and release with specific options.  So all in all not a useful question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x86 MUL Instruction from VS 2008/2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039378/x86-mul-instruction-from-vs-2008-2010)

Comment: same question for a different compiler, but has the same answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write C code so that the compiler emits `imul` with one operand then the only way is to use *widening signed multiplication*, i.e. cast the operand(s) to a signed type **twice the register length**. Hence in 32-bit mode the following code will produce the expected output

```
long long multiply(int x, int y) {
    return (long long)x * y;
}
```

Because [non-widening multiplication in 2's complement is the same for both signed and unsigned types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063665/995714), compilers will almost always use multi-operand `imul` as it's faster and more flexible.

In x86_64 compilers use multi-operand `imul` to produce 64-bit results even when the inputs were only 32-bits because they still typically have better latency and throughput than single-operand `imul`. As a result you'll also have to use a double-register-width (128-bit) type like above. Clang, ICC and GCC do support that via `__int128`, though.

- [What gcc versions support the __int128 intrinsic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21886985/995714)
- [Is there a 128 bit integer in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16088282/995714)

The below snippet

```
__int128_t multiply(long long x, long long y) {
    return  (__int128_t)x * y;
}
```

will be [compiled to](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukFqAK7Fk7DgHpXAajQsADnUweAO6ECB4AtCwAzGYeRB5KAcDIyB72Sh4CmGGoPpjEhugeeCz2tCYaAIK0AsAe1UYeJbQEeD60AJ4QeIIeqqRFPe0AlB4mAOxWlR4exJgEjgzTEPW1K0OqHgBUHu0mkZMV4wAi5YeV5pF4VFhUHgD6d0IAkgBa2ADyAGJ3TwByACpcMwADgepwe3QIQNBBEapRabXa0OWNTqqL6aIaKx2I3GB2mMzmCyWEME0LuBHWWx2ewOx1OF0Y%2BCopw4Q30nAArLwGJpeKhOABhazWeIOJwBC48UgEPlDdkAaxAZi4ADoxpyNJJgQBOYEa3XArhajkcSQ8vmkAUcXgKEAaGVy0hwWAwRAoVC%2BfxkCgQbx%2BejEEDABTMHwKBCoAh8OgEPJ2iAAI0tie6TGI7U40u8bEE7wYHUtWBYhmA4g4WlI%2BFmyBaADdMHaK7xMKpMMh7HGs7xIZhaJbaHhE/kM4KMC5pQRiMVu%2ByqAYQwA1PCYQLvXK87i8fiCERidhSGSCRQqdTN0i6Lj6UsoEWWfRDu2Qdk5FoCJthVQpMLvMy2vvtm%2BvIQEyY60PYLC8mYDpMgAMt0mC/BBiZ5CAwKkD4qAKIQeACGBEFQZyGFYThAjwQwiHIahYy2ABta4QwQgEOmBD4ZByoOko9D0QITEseRlEsChQboQozHEKxqDgexZhEWJ/EIUhQnUeydiOM4ehTpgE5sqa3KkJulbWqowIAGxhKZkgeEkKQQFO9gMAqIwQMKljWP0uCECQoxmJEV4eGOXqBj5flDLwsrNuyEBIP63rkJQsWBigBhGFIGgOjQzTxpQybnqmzAZt2pA5owBD5oW57FqW5aVtWgF4A2TaVq27adjp5CCH2A5DiO7RjlgRVTjOW5zguCjLqu66MEVO7CKI4iHrNJ5qJaujSClxh3jYg6Jk%2BEAvj4QEfl%2B4S/v%2B3FAZQoFSQRehwYpVFBlemHYUBbG8s9JFAQJSnCXoXH1bx4mSdJH20RdDF8RJP2Pf9wPvXDCkUb9qFcKp4oaVeWk6ey/YcPphn8pwJnmZZXgbR4Uiqho1MeC5W0efgRDECF/mBQGeQhZIYWOpFiogKZaqSJEWqRGMplmGYkimYaprmqQLAgJqBmWtatqaU6LruoleTxX6noc0GyAbRSxAOQqMZZcQCa5ZW%2BXppmW7FZ6uZlQWju1ZgJZGDVvB1fRjWWi1HZdk7vZ45WO29f17VDYrI18GNE1rhuM2yHuC3SEtSgreeuhmNeRi3m5947XtB1HZwETRKdf62BjB4yrMON6Ra57GWZFlWcbpZ0/ZjnOa5Vj3h4nnM6z/Ts96IVmDzEVaFFMUG3Fvo60GIZhhGUaW3G1s5SmaaFU7JV5u7RZe9VLi1XgNb1o2QdtiH7Xh91w4OzHg3TvHPCjUwS4rinaaTtZoZwPFnWQy0zyVl0JEQum0S7bUfPACuDFjrfl/OEKIdcAY8WAtdUGEgC73WRrDaQL1SIMARkCYir0GIw2UkGaQOCgJQxBrdahzDIbA3oX9Jh8MbrsQ4dwh6DCQDc3rupRu2NZytxVu3YmncyY2T7mbAedMh7uVHkzbyUpJ7L2ChcSIc9NZLyCrrVe%2BjUJ1mQD4Hwdw6xcB1HcPydwSY72ykmA%2BBVHbZhdqVcqHs/YXx9lfP2N96qB3PMHNqRUX7niju/ccn9ho/0Tn/caACpqbmlCA%2BaYCjzyBzlAnQSs4HF2Hog3ayCrSHVQSAVwv5waAzwQwdAVDSDEMEn9T6tC8ICLBuQ76IjulNNwaw9pnCgZIy6ajWw/CCFXnktDYZqN0aSM0s3GReMCaqwUaZRoChrEeAcTqVUfl1EMy0V5FmuiAqWJub5Tkxi%2BakAQJgJgWAgz7TlrwRWytCZWk4OrAu882T8zGMCVUUsdScmNECSQcLdSmkiG3IyQLeYL1xpwOuAK1YYrBaQBs1sGJiKAA%3D%3D)

```
mov     rax, rdi
imul    rsi
ret
```

If you use MSVC then you can use [`_umul128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/3dayytw9(v=vs.100)) in 64-bit mode

Comment: Your demo left out `-m32`, so gcc just uses a two-operand 64bit `imul`.  Also, in posts where you aren't hitting the character limit, non-shortened godbolt links are preferable [to avoid any chance of link-rot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319594/224132)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks. I put -m32 at first but then removed it to check the x86_64 code and forgot to include it again