# Is int64_t enough for banking? If not what are the alternatives?

Tags: c, integer, bank

I am writing a [personal finance cli](https://github.com/bharatvaj/payredu) in C and I want to make sure that it can handle the commodity sizes in real world and still be **very performant**.

The struct that holds the value is structured like this,

```c
typedef struct {
  int64_t before_decimal; // 9 pentillion before decimal
  uint32_t after_decimal; // 4 billion after decimal
} ledger_commodity_t;
```

int64_t has a range of -2^63 to 2^63-1 (9 pentillion) which I think is enough, even if one chooses to process our entire economy for some reason. And I assume using a BigInt is a waste of processing power in this particular case since it's possible to predict the range.

**Or am I wrong in assuming that?**

Wrapping silently is not an issue, as I'll will be the one parsing the ledger file, and will be able to throw an error if it happens.

libzahl, gmp, TomsFastMath, etc all look good, but I would rather avoid using any library, as I be only adding and subtracting within the range of global economy.

Comment: Back of the napkin math tells me that the world GDP in Iranian rial (the lowest-worth unit currency) is 4,200,111,935,582,878,000,000.00. Is this one of your use cases?

Comment: The "after decimal" part of your struct scares me. What unit does one "after decimal" represent?

Comment: Generally I think banks use 128 bit floats.

Comment: Start with the assumption that a commodity will overflow. If not today, then tomorrow. Even if this is the edge caseiest of edge cases, anyone using your API should have passing knowledge of Y2K, and the "upcoming" epoch bug (in 2038). They'll know that numbers have the potential to overflow and they'll want to know what happens when your API overflows. Put some well-defined behavior in your API to handle the case where operations would overflow.

Comment: @Verpous what are you basing that on? What bank uses floating point for money calculations?

Comment: @JohnFilleau General knowledge. Something I think I once heard. Could be wrong.

Comment: @Verpous, Using a float type doesn't make sense. 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 and 0.9 are all common numbers that can't be accurately represented by a float type.  These are periodic numbers in binary (like 1/3 in decimal), so they would take infinite storage to store as a float. (I mean, you could if you took precautions, but then why not simply use something better.)

Comment: Office Space or Superman 2 should both be required watching for computer science students.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Thanks for your input, 4 billion after decimal is indeed overkill, I should move some of it's bit to 'before_decimal'.

Comment: @ratj, fyi, Your approach is roughly the same as using a 96 bit int and working in 1 billionth of the currency. It's a lot easier to deal with a single int. The catch is finding a machine that provides 96 bit ints :)

Comment: @Verpous, there is not one financial institution that use floats for anything. There had been two once, but one went away, and now there are only 0.99999999999999999999999

Comment: `Or am I wrong in assuming that?` You could also work reactively, instead of proactively. Add some checks for overflow. If you or your users ever hit them, then you'll know you will need to move to uint128_t.

Comment: @Verpous `float` only holds significant 6 to 7 decimal digits, so it's worse than using `int` which can hold 9 significant digits.

Comment: @KamilCuk  I like what you're saying.

Comment: @JohnFilleau The edge case of Iranian rial is indeed alarming, but I think no one will ever attempt to do GDP in plain Iranian rial. I think throwing an error when overflow occurs would be the best way to stay performant and still be correct in almost every case as you and KamilCuk mentioned.

Comment: @ikegami I'm very new to this. Of course, simple math with 96 bits doesn't seem to be possible. I guess, sticking int64_t as default and making it customizable during build would be the right way to go.

Comment: You're not using int64_t. You're using int64_t + uint32_t. My point is that you can use a single int that uses "after_decimal" units

Comment: @WeatherVane: I agree that `float` would be silly, but Verpous did say 128-bit floats — that would be a `long double` or a compiler-specific type.  Those support many more digits, of course.  If the hardware supports floating point decimals, then the 128-bit decimal floating point numbers would be a good choice.  Otherwise, get an emulation of them, or use a decimal number package.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler mybad, I misread it.

Comment: Or do your own custom "MediumInt" with (exactly) two `uint64_t`.  Instead of classifying into before and after the decimal point on a storage-unit basis, use a fixed-point model.  That can give you 36 total decimal digits, with your choice of how many follow the (virtual) decimal point.

Comment: Using an unsigned value for the fraction is likely to cause some interesting gotchas when calculating with negative numbers.  You might consider using a separate sign bit (you've got plenty of padding bytes you can use) and unsigned integers for both parts of the value.  Or you might consider using signed numbers for both, with the consistency check that if the integer part of the value is negative, the fractional part is also negative or zero (remembering that the integer part could be zero and the fractional part still needs to be negative because someone is overdrawn by 37 cents/pennies/…).

Comment: If you don't mind using an extension to the c standard integer types, you can use __int128. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886985/what-gcc-versions-support-the-int128-intrinsic-type. Some compilers also support an unsigned 128 bit integer type, but such support is not as common. I suspect it would probably be faster to use this than to make your own composite type with a struct. You also need to remember to use aligned_alloc() or similar instead of malloc() and family if you make arrays of them or arrays of structs containing them as they have non-standard alignment requirements.

Comment: @Verpous This matter is serious. It is not acceptable to post guesswork about it. Please don’t.

Answer (score 1):

As the example of the Iranian rial given by @JohnFilleau shows, `int64_t` *might* be just a little too small.

As you have an `uint32_t` for the after decimal part, my recommendation would be to use that, and a currency dependent constant on how many digits/bits are shifted to that value.

Comment: @ikegami I see that you have more or less proposed the same in your comments. Sorry for steeling the idea.

Answer (score 1):

With the [next version of C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)#Keywords) (C2X, C24 or whatever), look to using *optional* [decimal floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) types such as `decimal64` for money.