# Is there a trick for calculating powers of two modulo a large prime using 64 bit ints fast?

Tags: c++, algorithm, modular-arithmetic

I just came up with this:

```
// calculates 2^n mod p
uint64_t twopow(uint64_t n, uint64_t p) {
    const constexpr uint64_t bitmask {18446744073709551615ull}; // 2^64-1
    uint64_t res = 1 << (n % 64);
    res *= modpow(1 + (bitmask ^ p), n >> 6, p);
    
    return res % p;
}
```

What it does is invert the bits of p by XOR-ing them against the integer that's all ones to get 2^64-p-1 which is equivalent to 2^64-1 mod p then add one and you get 2^64 mod p. Then writing n=64*a+b and 2^n=(2^64)^a*2^b.

In general I have p, n between 2^32 and 2^64. In this interval you can't multiply the integers directly or they overflow, so you have to use a workaround such as Montgomery modular arithmetic or Russian peasant multiplication which hurts the performance. The trick with the bitmask reduces n by 6 digits but in general it can still be as large as 2^58 and since the base of the exponential isn't 2 anymore we lose that (possible) advantage. Is there a trick for calculating 2^n mod p which is as fast as repeated squaring would be if p were less than 2^32?

Comment: Why haven't you used `~p` to "invert the bits of p"?

Comment: @Bob__ because I didn't know that operator existed in c++.

Comment: `-p` works even better because for `uint64_t` it's equal to 2^64 - p, which is congruent to 2^64 mod p.

Comment: I can't think of anything offhand except the `__uint128` extension.

Comment: [In GCC, Clang, ICC just use `__uint128` and in MSVC use `_umul128`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5288915/995714)